# Load Balancer SSL Issue: Not Trusted Warning Despite Valid OV Certificate

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-load-balancer

I've implemented a load balancer using my own OV certificate, which is valid until next year. Initially, everything was working fine, but I've encountered an issue where some users, including myself occasionally, are receiving a "Not Trusted" warning when visiting the website.

Upon investigation, I found that the GTS CA 1D4 certificate expired last September. According to my setup, this certificate shouldn't be present in the chain, as I've added my own valid certificate.

While tools like [SSLShopper](https://www.sslshopper.com) indicate that everything is okay, [SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) reports a different result.

I'm uncertain if this behavior is expected, especially when using a self-managed certificate. If this is indeed the case, how can I extend or update the expired GTS CA 1D4 certificate? Any insights or guidance on resolving this discrepancy would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**Update**

I had two front ends, one for http (for redirecting without www, and another one for https ipv4. I didn’t have one for ipv6. Now i added that one and remove the existing for http. Both shared same exact ssl certificate. Still don’t see changes

[new load balancer config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PAn0.png)

Comment: Not enough information. We need the endpoint to test with. In most cases, when an intermediate certificate expires, you must obtain a new certificate. Who did you purchase from? Contact them with the problem.

Comment: Sorry about that. My domain is startfire.cl and this will be the request https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=startfire.cl&hideResults=on&latest. The thing is in my proxy I don't see that expired google certificate at all. Neither in the chain that the company we got the certificate from. Also trying to get a n ew one from Google is getting stuck on FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE and based on documentation seems to be related to DNS configuration problems.

Comment: The certificate for your server is issued by USERTrust and is a wildcard certificate. The root and intermediate have not expired. Your site is being served via the GFE (Google Frontend). I think the problem is misconfigured IPv6 settings on your DNS server.

Comment: I just noticed. You are serving different certificates for IPv4 connections and IPv6 connections. The Google Trust certificate used for IPv6 has expired. Your certificate is expired. There are no issues with the intermediate or root certificates.

Comment: If you are using the Google Cloud load balancer, then you should have two frontends. One for IPv4 and another for IPv6. Configure the IPv6 frontend to use the same certificate as the IPv4 frontend. Update your post with details on how your configured the load balancer frontends.

Comment: Thanks @JohnHanley, trying to update my configuration. I had 2 front-end ones but one for ipv4 and the other one was http for a redirection to https. I added one extra front-end for ipv6 and both, ipv4 & ipv6, are using the same certificate. I guess I need these changes to propagate because still getting same results

Comment: You are still not using the same SSL certificate for both frontends. Many Internet tools will show you the certificate. When using those tools, you don't have to wait for propagation, which is a DNS issue, not a TLS issue.

Comment: In your last update, you mentioned that you did not have an IPv6 frontend. You most certainly did and you had DNS AAAA resource records. I recommend pausing for a moment and reviewing what you have and then reading the load balancer configuration documents. You might be overlooking something because what you say you configured does not match what is configured.

Comment: I shared a screenshot with my new config in the edited post

Comment: When you make changes to the load balancer that affect the IP address, you must also make changes to the DNS server for your domain. The IPv6 address in your configuration screenshot does not match your DNS server. I guess you did not read my comment: **what you say you configured does not match what is configured**.

Comment: Think of the network path: Customer -> DNS server (covert hostname to IP address). Customer -> IP address -> frontend -> backend. Each one of those path segments must be configured correctly.

Comment: Note: unless you have a good technical reason, always configure an IPv6 front end for port 80 if you configured port 443. Only having an IPv6 port 443 frontend will introduce problems that you may or may not see, but some customers will see a problem.

Comment: Working!!! omg, I missed this ipv4, ipv6 completely. I updated the frontend to http and saved. After that I went to the AAAA records and the ephemeral IP was available in the modal. Saved and it worked!

Comment: Make sure your IP addresses are reserved. Do not configure with ephemeral addresses.

Comment: yeah, I updated that part. Update the front-end and dns to use the static ipv6 IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem required solving several problems.

1. The load balancer frontends were configured with a self-managed and a Google-managed certificate. The SSL certificate for the IPv6 frontend had expired.
2. The load balancer IPv6 frontend was configured with a different IP address than the DNS server.
3. The load balancer was configured with ephemeral IP addresses.